# how to create this regular expression correctly  ,  jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I want to create a jQuery validation method to validate according to the following rules:

1. English letters . `A-Z , a-z` .
2. Non English letters `\u0080-\u024F` .
3. and for these characters   -  / )  (  `  .  "  '
4. and space character

Currently I am using:

```js
jQuery.validator.addMethod("custommethod", function(value, element) {
      return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z\u0080-\u024F ]+$/i.test(jQuery.trim(value));
    }, "You Have Typed Invalid Characters");
```

Currently I have done the validation for step 1,2,4. But when I try to add step 3 it fails.

How do I add step 3 to the validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add characters that may be part of a RegExp in escaped form:

```
/^[a-zA-Z\u0080-\u024F\s\/\-\)\(\."`']+$/i
   .test('.ab-"..c ëd ç -(// \')'); //=>true
```

[See also](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), especially *Table 4.1 Special characters in regular expressions.*

Answer (score 0):

```
 /^[a-z\u0080-\u024F \-\/\)\(\"\'\.\`]+$/i
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the regex below:

```
/^[a-zA-Z\u0080-\u024F\s-/)(`."']+$/i
```